# PostgreSQL and ActiveRecord subselect for race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm experiencing a race condition in ActiveRecord with PostgreSQL where I'm reading a value then incrementing it and inserting a new record:

```
num = Foo.where(bar_id: 42).maximum(:number)
Foo.create!({
  bar_id: 42,
  number: num + 1
})
```

At scale, multiple threads will simultaneously read then write the same value of `number`. Wrapping this in a transaction doesn't fix the race condition because the SELECT doesn't lock the table. I can't use an auto increment, because `number` is not unique, it's only unique given a certain `bar_id`. I see 3 possible fixes:

- Explicitly use a postgres lock (a row-level lock?)
- Use a unique constraint and retry on fails (yuck!)
- Override save to use a subselect, I.E.

  `INSERT INTO foo (bar_id, number) VALUES (42, (SELECT MAX(number) + 1 FROM foo WHERE bar_id = 42));`

All these solutions seem like I'd be reimplementing large parts of `ActiveRecord::Base#save!` Is there an easier way?

UPDATE:
I thought I found the answer with `Foo.lock(true).where(bar_id: 42).maximum(:number)` but that uses `SELECT FOR UDPATE` which isn't allowed on aggregate queries

UPDATE 2:
I've just been informed by our DBA, that even if we could do `INSERT INTO foo (bar_id, number) VALUES (42, (SELECT MAX(number) + 1 FROM foo WHERE bar_id = 42));` that doesn't fix anything, since the SELECT runs in a different lock than the INSERT

Comment: If it were computed on the fly, it would change over time, plus be subject to the same race condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are:

- Run in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation. Interdependent transactions will be aborted on commit as having a serialization failure. You'll get lots of error log spam, and you'll be doing lots of retries, but it'll work reliably.
- Define a `UNIQUE` constraint and retry on failure, as you noted. Same issues as above.
- If there is a parent object, you can `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the parent object before doing your `max` query. In this case you'd `SELECT 1 FROM bar WHERE bar_id = $1 FOR UPDATE`. You are using `bar` as a lock for all `foo`s with that `bar_id`. You can then know that it's safe to proceed, so long as every query that's doing your counter increment does this reliably. This can work quite well.

  This still does an aggregate query for each call, which (per next option) is unnecessary, but at least it doesn't spam the error log like the above options.
- Use a counter table. This is what I'd do. Either in `bar`, or in a side-table like `bar_foo_counter`, acquire a row ID using

  ```
  UPDATE bar_foo_counter SET counter = counter + 1
  WHERE bar_id = $1 RETURNING counter
  ```

  or the less efficient option if your framework can't handle `RETURNING`:

  ```
  SELECT counter FROM bar_foo_counter
  WHERE bar_id = $1 FOR UPDATE;

  UPDATE bar_foo_counter SET counter = $1;
  ```

  Then, *in the same transaction*, use the generated counter row for the `number`. When you commit, the counter table row for that `bar_id` gets unlocked for the next query to use. If you roll back, the change is discarded.

I recommend the counter approach, using a dedicated side table for the counter instead of adding a column to `bar`. That's cleaner to model, and means you create less update bloat in `bar`, which can slow down queries to `bar`.